# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un JSON a un array javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estoy comenzando con el intercambio de datos entre php y javascript y por tanto con JSON pero no entiendo como funciona exactamente, lo que quiero es pasar un array que tengo en php a JSON y este JSON a javascript, hasta ahora ya lo transformé en JSON pero no sé como pasarlo a javascript. Si me pueden aclarar con un ejemplo simple me ayudaría mucho, gracias.

```js
<?php
include "conexion.php";
 $sql=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos");
 $sql->execute();
 $fila=$sql->fetchall();
echo json_encode($fila);
 ?>
 
 
 
 [{"id":"15","0":"15","nombre":"Ukelele","1":"Ukelele","descripcion":"G450","2":"G450","precio":"1","3":"1","imagen":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","4":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","inventario":"100","5":"100","id_categoria":"1","6":"1","color":"","7":""},{"id":"16","0":"16","nombre":"Ukelele","1":"Ukelele","descripcion":"G450","2":"G450","precio":"1000000","3":"1000000","imagen":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","4":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","inventario":"100","5":"100","id_categoria":"1","6":"1","color":"","7":""},{"id":"17","0":"17","nombre":"Marihu","1":"Marihu","descripcion":"G450","2":"G450","precio":"1000000","3":"1000000","imagen":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","4":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","inventario":"100","5":"100","id_categoria":"1","6":"1","color":"","7":""},{"id":"18","0":"18","nombre":"Ukelele","1":"Ukelele","descripcion":"G450","2":"G450","precio":"1000000","3":"1000000","imagen":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","4":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","inventario":"100","5":"100","id_categoria":"1","6":"1","color":"","7":""},{"id":"19","0":"19","nombre":"Ukelele","1":"Ukelele","descripcion":"G450","2":"G450","precio":"1000000","3":"1000000","imagen":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","4":"ukelele-descuento.jpg","inventario":"100","5":"100","id_categoria":"1","6":"1","color":"","7":""}]
```

Comment: Tienes algún código para solicitar ese JSON en tu vista?

Comment: No sé como hacerlo, se debe hacer por medio de ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Espero que te sirva.! aca lo tenes con Jquery.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $("button").click(function(){

     $.get("datos.php", function(datos, status){

        var info = JSON.parse(datos); console.log(“string datos: ”, datos); 
        console.log(“JS_array -> ”, info);

     });

 });

});

</script>
```